# Storing data in a job for use when it is performed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I need to store information at the time an Active Job is scheduled for use when it is later performed.  I would like to save this information in the Active Job itself, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying, which reproduces a bug I see:

```
class TestJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  attr_reader :save_for_later

  def initialize(info)
    @save_for_later = info
  end


  def perform()
    logger.info(@save_for_later)
  end
end

class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
  def schedule_test_job
    TestJob.perform_later(Date.new)
  end
end
```

When I call schedule_test_job in the Collections controller, I get an error:
    undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
and the perform action is not called.

I'm assuming I need to persist the information I'm trying to save elsewhere in my database, but I'd like to know if there is a proper way to accomplish what I'm doing here. I also don't understand where the error thrown is coming from.

Comment: Where do you get that error? It probably because you shouldn't override intialize as it does some other stuff also. You can pass the date as job argument as it will be persisted but pass it as numeric because ActiveJob only accepts basic type (that can be easy serialized / deserialized). You can use `i=Time.current.to_i` and `Time.at(i)`

Comment: @bcd The error occurs when the function `schedule_test_job` in the controller is called.   To your point about initialize needing to do other stuff, this error does go away if I add a call to super() at the end of the initialize block.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all the job parameters are passed to `perform`, so you have to write:

```
class TestJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(date)
    logger.info(date)
  end
end

TestJob.perform_later(Date.new)
```

The second problem is that `Date` is not AFAIK serializable by ActiveJob. But you can easily pass a string and then parse the date ;)